# Chartboost example doesn't work on Android

Tags: android, ads

I've been trying to set up chartboost ads in my apps/games.But it is not working for me. I followed the instructions from the `sdk` download page, but it didn't work. Then I downloaded their example from the `github` through this link https://github.com/ChartBoost/client-examples The example doesn't work either.

The logcat view displays messages shown below.

```
 08-12 14:58:08.803: I/ChartBoost(9641): Request response received: Request received
 08-12 14:58:08.807: I/JSON(9641): {"message":"Request received","status":200}
 08-12 14:58:08.827: E/ChartBoost(9641): error generating request!
```

If someone has encountered similar problems or know any solutions to the problem, any help in appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you sign up for Chartboost, receive the signing key and make sure to correctly put that into your app? Just making sure since those are the most common problems.

The Chartboost support team will be the best source for helping you with this. Did you contact them also? They'll be back in the office on Monday.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I already did those things. But seems like nothing is working. I found that the ads are working on emulator somehow. So I'm now trying to add test device on the dashboard and see if it works.